# Highly granular access control of non-AWS resources in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've got an ASP.NET Web API that is using AWS Cognito for authentication and resource access control. We've been using user pool groups up until this point to define certain entities users have access to (non-aws resources in a DB).

The problem is, now that our requirements for access control are more detailed, we are hitting the group cap of 25 per pool. I've looked into alternatives within Cognito, such as using custom attributes, but I've found that there are also limits on the number of custom attributes per pool, as well as they only support string & number types, not arrays.

Another alternative I've explored is intercepting the token when it hits our API, and adding claims based on permissions mapped in the DB. This works reasonably well, but this is only a solution server side, and I'm not entirely thrilled with needing to intercept every request to add claims with a DB call (not great for performance). We need some of these claims client side as well, so this isn't a great solution.

Beyond requesting a service limit increase to the amount of groups available per pool, am I missing anything obvious? Groups seem to be the suggested way to do this, based on documentation from AWS. Even if we went for a multi-tenant approach with multiple pools, I think the 25 group cap is still going to be an issue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/scenario-backend.html

Comment: Can you request a limit increase?

Answer (score 0):

You can request limit increases for nearly any part of the service. They will consider. Sometimes this is more straightforward than building side systems, as you point out. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: I have requested a server limit increase, but I did want to ensure I'm not missing something obvious, because we are expecting fairly substantial scale and I'd like to avoid running into limits in the future.